# Use of unassigned local variable that does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

I am trying to add the concessionItem price to a list. I can not access the variable after the for loop is finished, because it is out of scope. I've tried writing totalCost above the foreach loop as well, but then it is not accessible within the logic.

```
public void PayForConcessions()
        {
            foreach (ConcessionItem ci in concessionItems)
            {
                decimal totalCost;
                totalCost += ci.Price;
            }

            this.RemoveMoney(totalCost);
        }
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko ```decimal totalCost = concessionItems.Sum(m=>m.Price);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign totalCost and move it before foreach loop

```
decimal totalCost = 0m;
foreach (ConcessionItem ci in concessionItems)
{
    totalCost += ci.Price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`decimal total cost;` needs to be declared inside the method body, but above the loop:

```c#
public void PayForConcessions()
{
    // HERE
    decimal totalCost = 0;

    foreach (...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

For the "use of unassigned local variable", you just need to assign the default value. So `decimal totalCost = 0;`

Comment: You're right, and that's what I understood to be correct. However when I type it like that, I am receiving the error "Use of unassigned local variable" inside of the foreach logic while assigning ci.Price to totalCost... That's the part I couldn't figure out when going about things your way.

Comment: Updated the answer. You just need to assign an initial value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried writing totalCost above the foreach loop as well,

I think you might have put it in the wrong place.. This should be fine:

```
    public void PayForConcessions()
    {
        decimal totalCost = 0;
        foreach (ConcessionItem ci in concessionItems)
        {
            totalCost += ci.Price;
        }
        this.RemoveMoney(totalCost);
    }
```

Basic rule of variable scoping; inside the same set of `{ }` brackets, or any nested brackets within, below the point of declaration..

Comment: This is triggering the error "Use of unassigned local variable totalCost". That's what I tried before posting this and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I see what you were saying. The issue I had is that I didn't assign the variable at all. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Yep, if you want to read up on it the phrase you need to google is "c# definite assignment"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *Linq* and get rid of loop at all:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public void PayForConcessions() => 
  RemoveMoney(concessionItems.Sum(ci => ci.Price));
```